# Wine / native ODBC integration

Tags: odbc, wine, sage-line-50

I'm trying to connect to a Sage Line 50 database (which is some awful old .DTA format) on a Linux machine. Sage provides ODBC drivers that work under Windows, and approximating the instructions [here](http://wiki.winehq.org/NativeOdbc) I've been able to get a DSN setup in Wine using native ODBC

When I try to access the DSN from a script though, I get a unixODBC error that "Data source name not found", presumably because unixODBC has no way to see/connect to the Wine DSN. It appears that programs running under Wine can access unixODBC DSNs, but is there any way to do it the other way, or does the script itself need to run within Wine?

Answer (score 0):

Wine doesn't export Windows ODBC drivers to *nix applications, only to Windows applications. The easiest way is probably to run your script under Wine.